# Javascript getElementById does not work on chrome but works on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom

Good Morning,
I have this code

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML = "Order Placed Cheack your email!";
    document.getElementById("button").style.display = "none";
}
```

The above code when executed works on Firefox but when I run it on Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit) or Edge or IE browser it does not gives any response

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Form</title>
            <script defer src="form.js/"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <p id="confirm">Confirm order?</p>
            <button id="button">Submit</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Just tested using Chrome and it seems to be working fine. Are you missing some code? Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kdty9c3e/

Comment: The same code on jsfiddle.net/kdty9c3e does not works on Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit) @AndroidNoobie

Comment: Wrap the JS in a `window.addEventListener(“DOMContentLoaded”, () => {/* add listeners here */})` callback. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: The fiddle works fine for me in that version of Chrome.

Comment: When it doesn't work, are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @1252748 The `defer` attribute is supposed to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things, please put the `<script src="form.js"></script>` just before the body and also, remove the `defer` attribute and `/` after `form.js`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="confirm">Confirm order?</p>
        <button id="button">Submit</button>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
</html>
```

The above should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are including your JavaScript before the DOM is ready so the click event is not getting attached properly due to fast loading of the JS file in Chrome V8 engine.
Always remember to put your script tag just before the close of html tag. Also, you are missing `type="text/javascript"`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Form</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <p id="confirm">Confirm order?</p>
            <button id="button">Submit</button>
        </body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
    </html>
```

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` isn't required now-a-days.